# How to place a Widget above a widget with proportional size and position

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

I want a group of widgets to be placed proportionally above a background Widget (Image widget).

[image]

I tried the following.
Created a `Widget` array and added it to `Stack` Used `LayoutBuilder` to build child widgets nad positioned them using `Positioned` widget.

But it didn't work due to `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.` error.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _widgetStack = <Widget>[];
    _widgetStack.add(Container(
      child: Image.network(
          'https://nikhileshwar96.github.io/Showcase/blue.jpg'),
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
    ));
    for (int _i = 1; _i < 5; _i++) {
      _widgetStack.add(LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constrain) => Positioned(
                top: constrain.maxWidth * 0.5,
                left: constrain.maxHeight * 0.5,
                width: constrain.maxWidth * 0.25,
                height: constrain.maxHeight * 0.25,
                child: Container(
                  child: Text('HiTHERE'),
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
                ),
              )));
    }

    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Hi there"),
        ),
        body: 
          Container(
            height: 500,
            child: Stack(
              children: _widgetStack,
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
child: CustomMultiChildLayout(
  delegate: FooDelegate([
    Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 1, 1),
    Rect.fromLTWH(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.05),
    Rect.fromLTWH(0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.05),
  ]),
  children: [
    LayoutId(id: 0, child: Container(color: Colors.grey)),
    LayoutId(id: 1, child: Material(color: Colors.red, child: InkWell(onTap: () {},))),
    LayoutId(id: 2, child: Material(color: Colors.blue, child: InkWell(onTap: () {},))),
  ],
)
```

the custom `MultiChildLayoutDelegate` could look like (however it is completely up to you how you implement the delegate):

```
class FooDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  final List<Rect> rects;

  FooDelegate(this.rects);

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    var id = 0;
    for (var rect in rects) {
      var childRect = Rect.fromLTWH(
        size.width * rect.left,
        size.height * rect.top,
        size.width * rect.width,
        size.height * rect.height);
      print('$childRect $size');
      positionChild(id, childRect.topLeft);
      layoutChild(id, BoxConstraints.tight(childRect.size));
      id++;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks pskink. I saw your comment. I'm reading the docs. I'm trying this.

Comment: Everything is superclear. I'll check this in my code and comment here.

Comment: btw `CustomMultiChildLayout` support animations out-of-the-box, see https://gist.github.com/pskink/ba475f88ba1853bec95ee9b7776e7184

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, festive days here. Your answer works great in simple sample. But in my code I get this `RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
` error as Infinite constrain was set to a widget in widget tree, need to find a way around this. I'm marking this as answer as yours achieves what was asked in query. Thanks.

Comment: most likely you are inside some `Row` / `Column` without `Expanded` widget

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html):

> A Positioned widget must be a descendant of a Stack, and the path from
> the Positioned widget to its enclosing Stack must contain only
> StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets (not other kinds of widgets, like
> RenderObjectWidgets).

To solve your issue:
You can use the `Transform` widget's `Transform.translate` constructor instead of the `Positioned` widget. So your code looks like this:

```
for (int _i = 1; _i < 5; _i++) {
 _widgetStack.add(LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constrain) {
            return Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(constrain.maxWidth * 0.5, constrain.maxHeight * 0.5),
            child: Container(
              width: constrain.maxWidth * 0.25,
              height: constrain.maxHeight * 0.25,
              child: Text('HiTHERE'),
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
            ),
          );
          }));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Your answer works well. But there is an issue regarding gestures with Transform [gesture issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27587). I'll keep this open for other options.

Comment: Also consider a FittedBox.